# Daemon doesn't start at boot - how can I debug this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I installed new relic according to their quick install instructions.

If I start the daemon manually after boot with `/etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon restart` it works, but it doesn't run automatically after boot. How can I find out why?

The servers are Scalr/AWS PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try searching through dmesg, /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog whyc is it happening so but there is a workaround:

1) Try running `chkconfig newrelic-daemon on`

2) If (1) doesn't help, try forcing the start by adding `/etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon restart` to /etc/rc.local, this should be placed there before any `exit` statement in /etc/rc.local

Comment: You should also check /var/log/boot.log for error messages

Answer (score 6):

I'd try running this manually with debug setting, as you know the argument to the program will be 'start'.  Using 'restart' may execute a path that works.

I'd first try:

```
 sh -vx /etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon start
```

And go through the output and see if it is working right.

Then you can do through and to the chkconfig.

As there are other newer startup processes, you should describe which Linux you are running.  This can usually be done by executing the command

```
cat /etc/*release.
```

Comment: Thanks, Here is the data:
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS"

Answer (score 2):

If in Ubuntu, at least: try running `sudo update-rc.d newrelic-daemon defaults` to create symlinks for /etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon (it has to exist first for the command to succeed).